# Porting HTML 5 page to a webBrowser object in winforms

Tags: c#, html, winforms, winforms-to-web

I'm trying to port [THIS](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/177/index.html) pasge and its HTML5 animation to a winform.
What I did is copied and added the `index.html` and all the `css` and `js` file to my project. This is how my project directory looks like

[image]

And then I'm trying to load the html file into my webbrowser object using this code snippet

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        this.webBrowser2.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/index.html", curDir));
    }
```

And I have set properties of all the file to `Copy Always`
Now when I run the project I get a script error message and upon pressing `Yes`
it loads the page but only background is displayed and the animation is lost!

please help!

PS: I've changed

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/ThreeWebGL.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ThreeExtras.js"></script>
```

To

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="ThreeWebGL.js"></script>
    <script src="ThreeExtras.js"></script>
```

in index.html file

Screenshots of two script error that I'm getting--
[image]
[image]

It works in IE10
[image]

Comment: Are we supposed to read your mind to determine what the script error is?

Comment: Can it be created locally?

Answer (score 2):

The *.js files need to be in a js folder. Either create the folder and move them or edit the html file.

**EDIT1:**
Does it work if you point it to "http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/177/index.html"?

**EDIT2:** 
Add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

in the html head section.

**EDIT3:**

I tried on my machine and it's the same behavior. But the page does run fine in Internet Explorer 11. Maybe the WinForms control uses IE engine in some compatibility mode.
I would use http://www.awesomium.com/

Comment: I've edited them before ive posted it here and its still the same

Comment: Point which script? all of them? or the web browser object? Can you be bit specific please?

Comment: @envyM6 The browser object

Comment: Script Error is gone but now the winform just freezes. No animation

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser control is just an instance of IE - that page doesn't work for me in Internet Explorer so it's unlikely to work in the embedded browser. Search for webkit net - might give you better results. I'm tempted to ask why you want to do this but I'm sure you've got a good reason.

Comment: Basically I want this effect to be my background on winform app (not sure if thats possible yet but one step at a time). So playing with it

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Basically the set up works fine. Just had to open `main.css` file and comment out all the footer properties to get rid of the footer and found another script ref which was pointed to `js/script.js` had to change it to `script.js`

[image]

Now how can i increase the framerate so that it doesnt stutter? Theres a lag at the moment